# Finding AIC and R-square in regression loop

Tags: r, loops, regression

I found many similar questions but I did not find something that could help me in the following scenario.  Thanks in advance and sorry for repetition. This is my data:

```
data_model3 <- structure(list(Year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017, 2018, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 
2017, 2018, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("mortality_rate_all_ages", 
"mortality_rate_under1y", "mortality_rate_1to10y", "mortality_rate_10to20y", 
"mortality_rate_20to30y", "mortality_rate_30to40y", "mortality_rate_40to50y", 
"mortality_rate_50to60y", "mortality_rate_60to70y", "mortality_rate_70to80y", 
"mortality_rate_80to90y", "mortality_rate_above90y"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0.0088, 0.0077, 0.0082, 0.0075, 0.0076, 0.0075, 
    0.0066, 0.0061, 0.0059, 0.0054, 0.0054, 0.0058, 0.0056, 0.006, 
    0.0053, 0.0061, 0.0052, 0.0055, 0.0069, 0.0074, 0.0073, 0.5823, 
    0.5251, 0.514, 0.4852, 0.5144, 0.4615, 0.4043, 0.3615, 0.3565, 
    0.3209, 0.3234, 0.3443, 0.3347, 0.357, 0.3025, 0.3309, 0.2778, 
    0.2551, 0.3197, 0.3299, 0.2679, 0.0098, 0.0069, 0.0098, 0.0086, 
    0.0073, 0.0106, 0.0058, 0.007, 0.0052, 0.0055, 0.0051, 0.0059, 
    0.0063, 0.0061, 0.0066, 0.0048, 0.0043, 0.0053)), row.names = c(NA, 
60L), class = "data.frame")
```

For each age group, I want to perform a polynomial regression and get beta coefficients, SE, p values, AIC, adjusted R square values.

I did the following but I do not know how to get AIC and adjusted R square values to the regression loop and save them in new columns next to the P value column:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

poly1_all_ages <- data_model3 %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  do(tidy(lm(value ~ poly(Year, 1), .))) %>% 
  mutate(Beta = as.character(round(estimate, 6)), "P Value" = round(p.value, 6), SE = round(std.error, 6)) %>% 
  select(Beta, SE, "P Value") %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

The outcome I get is:

```
                 variable      Beta       SE  P Value
1 mortality_rate_all_ages  0.006562 0.000206 0.000000
2 mortality_rate_all_ages -0.002494 0.000944 0.016081
3  mortality_rate_under1y  0.379471 0.009440 0.000000
4  mortality_rate_under1y -0.381255 0.043261 0.000000
5   mortality_rate_1to10y  0.006717 0.000302 0.000000
6   mortality_rate_1to10y  -0.00564 0.001281 0.000446
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`broom::tidy()` is for predictor-specific information. You will need `broom::glance()` to get model-specific information like the AIC.

For each level of variable, the following code

1. fits the model
2. extracts the predictor-related information into a long format using `broom::tidy()`
3. pivots #2 long format into wide format so all the predictor information is in a single row
4. extracts the model-related information using `broom::glance()`
5. column binds the predictor- and model-level information together

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)

data_model3 %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  do({
    my_mdl <- lm(value ~ poly(Year, 1), .)
    my_tidy <- tidy(my_mdl)
    my_tidy_wide <- pivot_wider(my_tidy, names_from = "term", values_from = everything())
    my_glance <- glance(my_mdl)
    bind_cols(my_tidy_wide, my_glance)
  }) %>% 
  select(variable, 
         starts_with("estimate"), 
         starts_with("std.error"), 
         starts_with("p.value"), 
         AIC, 
         adj.r.squared)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you also for providing explanation